# Predictor and response variables must have the same length; Matlab

Tags: matlab, error-handling, regression

Thanks in advance for the help.

I am trying to use stepwise regression on a set of data.  I have the data in a table, with the single predictor variable on the far right of the table (as a column).  Here is what my code looks like.

```
mdl = stepwiseglm(dummyTrainingTable,'modelspec',modelTech,'Criterion',criterion);
```

where modelTech and criterion are variables that hold strings dictating two name-value pair options.  I am getting the following error

```
Error using classreg.regr.FitObject/assignData (line 257)
Predictor and response variables must have the same length.

Error in classreg.regr.TermsRegression/assignData (line 349)
        model =
        assignData@classreg.regr.ParametricRegression(model,X,y,w,asCat,varNames,excl);

Error in GeneralizedLinearModel/assignData (line 794)
        model =
        assignData@classreg.regr.TermsRegression(model,X,y,w,asCat,dummyCoding,varNames,excl);

Error in GeneralizedLinearModel.fit (line 1165)
        model =
            assignData(model,X,y,weights,offset,binomN,asCatVar,dummyCoding,model.Formula.VariableNames,exclude);

Error in GeneralizedLinearModel.stepwise (line 1271)
            model = GeneralizedLinearModel.fit(X,y,start.Terms,'Distribution',distr,
            ...

Error in stepwiseglm (line 148)
model = GeneralizedLinearModel.stepwise(X,varargin{:});
```

This doesn't make sense to me since clearly my response and predictor variables have the same length; they're in a table together.  If they weren't the same length, they couldn't be in a table right?  Is this an issue with Matlab or is there just something simple that I am missing?

Note, I when I convert the table to a matrix, stepwiseglm runs just fine. i.e.,

```
dummyTrainingArray = table2array(dummyTrainingTable);

mdl = stepwiseglm(dummyTrainingArray(:,1:size(dummyTrainingArray,2) - 1), dummyTrainingArray(:,size(dummyTrainingArray,2)),modelTech,'VarNames', ...
    dummyTrainingTable.Properties.VariableNames,'Criterion', criterion);
```

Comment: One weird argument of the function (in the call you posted) is `'modelspec'`. It should not appear as such, but be replaced with an actual model specification, like `'constant'`, `'linear'` etc. The model specification is not a pair ArgName/ArgValue: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/stepwiseglm.html#inputarg_modelspec

Comment: modelspec can be used as a name value pair.

Comment: Well, I cannot test right now... but, if you insert the `'modelspec'` literal among the arguments in the successful `stepwiseglm` call, does it still work? If is not that, you can always open the .m files, put breakpoints, and debug  step by step until you figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Correction, you cannot use model spec as a name value pair.  That wasn't the problem though.

Comment: Agreed, it was just **a** problem. :-) I think it would be useful if you'd specify the version of your MATLAB release in the answer you gave, for the sake of the next users that might encounter the same problem and forget to check the help beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution.  Although the documentation online states that the input can be a table, when I checked the manual within my version of Matlab (run 'help stepwiseglm'), I found that the function was compatible only with datasets.  I then converted my table to a dataset and it ran fine.

Edit, I have Matlab version 
8.2.0.701 (R2013b)

Answer (score 0):

`'modelspec'` is not a valid argument name for the function. Try:

```
mdl = stepwiseglm(dummyTrainingTable, modelTech, 'Criterion', criterion);
```

Comment: That doesn't work;I've tried that as well.  I get this error "Wrong number of arguments".